# Swift 3.0: Change a button color once pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've created a circular green button. Here is the **CircularButton.swift** where I've defined color and shape as below:

```
import UIKit

class CircularButton: UIButton {

@IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.green

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
    fillColor.setFill()
    path.fill()

    }
}
```

Here is the screen shot.

[image]

On the button pressed I would like to change its color to red. I've defined the function as below:

```
@IBAction func circularButtonPressed(_ sender: CircularButton) {
    sender.fillColor = UIColor.red
    sender.draw(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sender.frame.width,
                       height: sender.frame.height))
}
```

Any idea why the color is not changed to red?

**Note**: If I add below line:

```
sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

in the above function, the button color changes to red.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Read about [the view drawing cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW10).

Comment: Thank you for the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `draw(_:)` from inside your code directly.
You just need to tell iOS that the control needs to be redrawn.

Remove the line calling `draw(_:)`:

```
@IBAction func circularButtonPressed(_ sender: CircularButton) {
    sender.fillColor = UIColor.red
}
```

And add observer to the `fillColor` property:

```
@IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.green {
    didSet(oldColor) {
        if fillColor != oldColor {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for.