# Fill button icon when button pressed in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button with icon, I want when pressed button icon fill with color and when pressed again empty color and return to the previous state

[image]

**Note:** As much as possible I do not want to change  icon after every pressed.

Comment: You can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937700/swift-3-0-change-a-button-color-once-pressed

Comment: @MdRashedPervez I don't want change button backColor!!! I want fill button icon color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is example how you can achieve that, let me know if you don’t understand something.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var someBtn: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureUI()
    }

    //Setting up images for normal and selected state.
    func configureUI() {
        let image = UIImage(named: "image")
        let imageFilled = UIImage(named: "image-filled")
        someBtn.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        someBtn.setImage(imageFilled, for: .selected)
    }

    @IBAction func someBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // Toggle basically makes someBtn’s selected state either true or false when pressed
        someBtn.isSelected.toggle()
    }
}
```

Comment: @GiaJoli new features in Swift 4.2: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/77/whats-new-in-swift-4-2

Comment: in swift 4 `toggle()` is don't exist. but your answer is perfect. Thank's

Comment: `someBtn.isSelected = !someBtn.isSelected` try this one instead of `toggle()` if it is not working. Glad to hear if it helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can call `setImage(_:for:)` method to set the image of the button for a particular state.

The button is at the `normal` state when the user is not pressing it, so you should do:

```
yourButton.setImage(hollowHeart, for: .normal)
```

The button is at the `highlighted` state when the user is touching it, so you should do:

```
yourButton.setImage(filledHeart, for: .highlighted)
```

You just need to do this once after you create the button, probably in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: don't work for me! create button in storyboard, but set normal state in viewDidLoad. nothing happened!

Comment: @GiaJoli You need to set the filled image for highlighted state as well. Did you do that?

Comment: Yep! in viewDidLoad code is: `LikeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Like"), for: .normal)`, and in button click code is: `LikeBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "LikeFill"), for: .highlighted)`

Comment: @GiaJoli no, you should not put that in button click. Put the second line in `viewDidLoad` as well.